# Search Function on a plugin Wordpress User

Tags: users, search

I am using the [plugin Wordpress User](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-users/) to display all the users in a single page. Now I am planning to create a search form which is not included in the plugin's function...

But I'm having hard time to do it, that's why I am asking for a help now.
I pasted the code at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cYMnCxQm) because it's too long to paste here.

The search form should work like "%like%" of SQL, meaning if I search "ad" it should display all the users that has "ad" on their username like "admin".